# Azure Document Translator is not working though response status is 202

Tags: python, azure, azure-cloud-services, language-translation

I have started learning about clouds. I am trying to use the **Azure Translation Service** to translate a Document. The hierarchy of the BLOB is given below.

|-storage account
|--container1
|---translation-input
|----sampleTranslation.docx
|---translation-output
I want to translate *sampleTranslation.docx* and store it in a separate file under *translation-output* folder.
I am doing the API call from POSTMAN. The **response status** is **202** (means successful) but there is no response body. The translation is also not happening.
When the same JSON is sent from Python, it given the below error:

> The JSON value could not be converted to Microsoft.MT.Batch.Contracts.Api.V1.StartTranslationDetails. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 590.

Can you please tell what I am doing wrong?
POSTMAN screenshot  is attached.
[Postman API Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bloaG.jpg)

Python Code:

```
subscription_key = CONSTANTS["TRANSLATOR_TEXT_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY"]
region = CONSTANTS["TRANSLATOR_TEXT_REGION"]
endpoint = CONSTANTS["TRANSLATOR_DOC_ENDPOINT"]

constructed_url = endpoint + "/translator//text//batch//v1.0//batches"

    headers = {
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key,
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region": region,
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "X-ClientTraceId": str(uuid.uuid4()),
    }
    
    body = json.dumps(
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "source": {
                    "sourceUrl": sourceUrl,
                },
                "targets": [
                    {
                        "targetUrl": targetUrl,
                        "language": "fr"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    )
    
    request = requests.post(
        constructed_url, headers=headers, json=body, verify=False
    )
    response = request.json()
    
    print("Request URL:\t", constructed_url)
    print("Response:\t")
    print(
        json.dumps(
            response,
            sort_keys=True,
            indent=4,
            ensure_ascii=False,
            separators=(",", ": "),
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP status code 202** means that the request has been accepted for processing, this is a normal response for long-running operations such as batch translation jobs.

I have tried to repro the above requirement. I have used the below code.
Thanks for the reference @[Shweta Lodha](https://github.com/shwetalodha/BlogSource/blob/main/TranslateDocFromEnfToFr_C%23.cs)

```py
import requests
import json

route = "/batches"
endpoint = "https://ejinfckad.cognitiveservices.azure.com/translator/text/batch/v1.0"
key = "f054332b55f94072a46e004e3e230f43"

json_data = {
    "inputs": [
        {
            "source": {
                "sourceUrl": "https://wdcw.net/xwx?sp=racwdli&st=2023-04-29T07:37:52Z&se=2023-04-29T15:37:52Z&sv=2021-12-02&sr=c&sig=dcdswdcw %3D",
                "storageSource": "AzureBlob"
            },
            "targets": [
                {
                    "targetUrl": "https://xxwnet/dw1?sp=rcwl&st=2023-04-29T07:35:43Z&se=2023-04-29T15:35:43Z&sv=2021-12-02&sr=c&sig=BI7BjOC%2FLJOMndxwY4Rl9BD%2FDJwybt7MQ%3D",
                    "storageSource": "AzureBlob",
                    "language": "fr"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

headers = {
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": key,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.post(endpoint + route, headers=headers, json=json_data)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Operation successful with status code: ", response.status_code)
else:
    print("Error occurred. Status code: ", response.status_code)
```

**Output:**  As expected.
[image]

But when I check in the target container I can see the translated file as per the requirement.
[image]

You can see the Docx file translated from eng to french.
[image]